# Speech to Text using Python & PyAudio not working on OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pyaudio

I am trying to use the Speech Recognition library on Python 3.7 (OS X/internal microphone)

Here's the code I am using so far:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
```

However, there is no output and no error message when I run the program. But when I hit the "stop" button, this error message turns up

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/diandraelmira/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/APP.py", line 6, in 
>       audio = r.listen(source)
>     File "/Users/diandraelmira/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py", line 620, in listen
>       buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
>     File "/Users/diandraelmira/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py", line 161, in read
>       return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
>     File "/Users/diandraelmira/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
>       return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
>   KeyboardInterrupt

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you please try this and will look for the errors

```
try:
    print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is need to little bit changes in your code and it is :

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rObject = sr.Recognizer() 
audio = '' 
with sr.Microphone() as source: 
    print("Speak...")   
    audio = rObject.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 0) 
    print("Stop.")
    try: 
        text = rObject.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-US') 
        print("You : "+ text)  
    except: 
        speak("Could not understand your audio...PLease try again !")
```

Try this ! Hope error will be solved .

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
#import library

import speech_recognition as sr

# Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)

r = sr.Recognizer()

# Reading Microphone as source
# listening the speech and store in audio_text variable

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Talk")
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    print("Time over, thanks")
# recoginize_() method will throw a request error if the API is unreachable, hence using exception handling
    
    try:
        # using google speech recognition
        print("Text: "+r.recognize_google(audio_text))
    except:
         print("Sorry, I did not get that")
```

Hopefully it works.